# ExtJS, SenchaTouch - FormPanel can't load values from a store?

Tags: sencha-touch, local-storage, extjs, formpanel

How do you load values into a formpanel from a store? I've built an [entire broken example here](http://www.stefankendall.com/files/stackoverflow/broken/test.html).

I'm not sure why my form fields aren't loaded.

**The model:**

```
Ext.ns('app', 'app.defaults');
        Ext.regModel('MyModel', {
            fields: [
                {name: 'var1', type: 'integer'}
            ]
        });
        app.defaults.vars = {
            var1: 5
        };
```

**The store:**

```
 var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
                    model: 'MyModel',
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'localstorage',
                        id: 'model-proxy'
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        load: function(store, records, successful) {
                            if (this.getCount() > 1) {
                                alert('Error: More than one record is impossible.');
                                this.proxy.clear();
                            }
                            if (this.getCount() == 0) {
                                alert( "Count 0, loading defaults");
                                this.add(app.defaults.vars);
                                this.sync();
                            }

                            console.log("Attempting to load store");
                            myForm.load(this);
                        }
                    },
                    autoLoad: true,
                    autoSave: true
                });
```

**The form:**

```
var myForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
                    id: 'my-form',
                    scroll: 'vertical',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'fieldset',
                            defaults: {
                                labelWidth: '35%'
                            },
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'numberfield',
                                    id: 'var1',
                                    name: 'var1',
                                label: 'Var1',
                                placeHolder: '100',
                                useClearIcon: true
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            });
```

Comment: @Gregory Nozik: Updated with the model. It's in the source of the 1-page live example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found other way to connect formpanel with the data
After the form is loaded insert following code

```
  myForm.getForm().loadRecord(Ext.ModelManager.create({
                        'var1':5
                    }, 'MyModel'));
```

So, then, load a record instead of the store. Load `records[0]` instead of `this`.

Comment: `.load` or `.loadRecord` work, so long as you pass in a record and not a store. I added the fix to your answer.